# generate a matrix with random values specified in a interval

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to generate a matrix with random values between 1 to 10 having 2 columns and rows equal to `days`. But with the below code, I am getting same values of random number in alternate rows like 2 2, 4 4, 2 2, 4 4 and so on.

```
days<-10
matrix1<-matrix(round(runif(days,1,10)),nrow = days,ncol = 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
matrix1<-matrix(round(runif(2*days,1,10)),nrow = days,ncol = 2)
```

Currently, the line `runif(days,1,10))` only requests 10 values, but you want 20 values. `matrix()` just recycles the 10 values since it expects 20.

Also, if you want the numbers 1-10 in equal proportion, you should use `sample(1:10, 2*days, replace = TRUE)` instead of `round(runif(...))`.